# Problem in Using Context Menus?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, contextmenu

I am using Windows forms in .NET 2.0.

I have used Split Container in my application with two Context Menus. I want that one context menu is associated with panel1 of split container & another context menu is associated with panel2 of split container.

Till Now the things go very fine. I am using context menu property of panel1 & panel2 of split container and assign context menus to both panel.

The problem is that when my application is running the first context menu of panel1 is Enabled and working properly but when I am doing right click on panel2, the context menu appears but it is disabled. I can't find any problem.

My question is that Is it possible to use two context menus for panel1 and panel2 in split container control? If it is possible then how to use it.

And another thing I mention here is that I am not using MDI control and I set IsMDIContainer property of my form to false.

Comment: This works fine for me.  Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me too.  I set up a Windows Forms / 2.0 app with a split container. I assigned a different context menu to each side and it worked like a champ.  I even added some child controls to panel2 and the context menu still displayed correctly when right clicking those controls.

Do you happen to have any click event handling code in the code behind?

Comment: yeah I do coding for context menu strips but I can't find whats the actual problem?

Comment: Yeah it worked fine for me too. Actually I disable context menu and when certain condition met, I only Enable context menu. So the problem is that, I am not Enabling context menu other options, only enabling context menu. Thanks for help